# Excel Matching Leftmost characters to a string in an entire column

Tags: excel, match, countif

I'm trying to figure out how to do this...

Say I have

```
A        B (LENGTH)

aa       2
bb       2
ba       2
aac      3
bac      3
aabc     4
bacb     4
aada     4
```

I want to compare to see if any are at the beginning of another string and count them.

So the output should be:

```
A        

aa       3
bb       1
ba       3
aac      1
bac      1
bacb     1
aada     1
```

This would compare to any in the row (including itself), so 1 means no other strings matched.

I tried doing something with LEFT, but can't figure out how to get the range in there correctly.

Something like this

=COUNTIF(LEFT($A$1,$B$1):LEFT(A10,B10),A1)

But I cant put the left function inside a range like that.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need an array formula.

```
=COUNT(IF(LEFT(A$1:A$8,LEN(A1))=A1,1))
```

Hold CTRL + SHIFT then hit ENTER.

Then drag this fomula through B8.

This will add {} around the formula making it an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT($A$1:$A$8,B1)=A1))
```